# pyparsing list of lists and values

Tags: python, pyparsing

A mock version of the code that I am trying is the following. I have many more cases of what a `SingleValue` is, and other constructions, but this is the part I am failing to represent.

```
import pyparsing as pp

SingleValue = pp.Word(pp.alphas)  # Single values are strings of letters
ListOfValues = pp.Forward()  # To be defined later
Values = SingleValue ^ ('{' + ListOfValues + '}')  # Values are either words or braces-enclosed lists
ListOfValues <<= pp.delimited_list(Values, delim=' ')  # The lists inside the braces are space-separated values.

print(ListOfValues.parse_string('{aaa bbb {ccc ddd}}'))
```

The comments indicate what I am expecting to represent in each line. The intension is that the string in the example is a valid `ListOfValues`: A braces enclosed, space separated, of either words or further lists.

The sample code gives

```
pyparsing.exceptions.ParseException: Expected {W:(A-Za-z) ^ {'{' Forward: None '}'}}, found 'bbb'  (at char 5), (line:1, col:6)
```

I also tried

```
Values = SingleValue ^ ListOfValues
ListOfValues <<= '{' + pp.delimited_list(Values, delim=' ') + '}'
```

This gives

```
pyparsing.exceptions.ParseException: Expected '}', found 'bbb'  (at char 5), (line:1, col:6)
```

How to define this?

---

It looks like the following works in this case

```
SingleValue = pp.Word(pp.alphas)  # Single values are strings of letters
Values = pp.Forward()
ListOfValues = '{' + pp.delimited_list(Values[...], delim=' ') + '}'  # The lists inside the braces are space-separated values.
Values <<= SingleValue | ListOfValues  # Values are either words or braces-enclosed lists

print(ListOfValues.parse_string('{aaa bbb {ccc ddd}}'))
```

This gives

```
['{', 'aaa', 'bbb', '{', 'ccc', 'ddd', '}', '}']
```

Although I still don't understand the reasoning why the first version in the question is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pyparsing module’s default behaviour is to ignore the leading whitespace. (see [1.1.2 Usage notes](https://pyparsing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HowToUsePyparsing.html#usage-notes))

That means `Literal(' ')` won't match and `delimited_list` will stop parsing

For non-skipping whitespace, there is `pp.White`:

```
ListOfValues <<= '{' + pp.delimited_list(Values, delim=pp.White(' ')) + '}'
```

You could also use `Values[...]` instead, although it will accept any number of whitespaces as a delimiter:

```
ListOfValues <<= '{' + Values[...] + '}'
```

Comment: As in `ListOfValues = '{' + Values[...] + '}'`  ? (Although I didn't specify, multiple whitespaces is ok for me).

Comment: @owl yes, exactly